# Relative Path to Grails test Directory

Tags: testing, grails

I created a folder under the test directory to store some files needed for our tests.  How can I access this directory via a relative path?  I looked into the GrailsResourceUtils but it seems to only deal with the grails-app directory.

For example, I need to access something like:

```
test/artifacts/file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, it would seem this was as easy as that exact path:

```
new File("test/artifacts/file.txt")
```

resolves just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer to put test resources in the same directory as the test class(es) that use them. Then you can load the resource from the test class using

```
InputStream testResource = getClass().getResourceAsStream('file.txt')
```

or

```
URL testResource = getClass().getResource('file.txt')
```