# grails unit testing a file path

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I'm trying to help unit test a grails application that does crazy things with files. One of the methods generates a disk path and need advice on how to test the returned file path. The file path will be different depending which computer it is ran on so i can't hardcode anything. Maybe use a regular expression that checks to see if backslashes are being used along with words in between?

```
def 'disk path is generated'() {
    when: 'a file is uploaded'
    final file = new GrailsMockMultipartFile("myFile", "foo".bytes)
    def manifest = Manifest.build()
    UploadedFile uploadedfile = UploadedFile.build(manifest: manifest, currentPath: file)

    then: 'test passes'
    service.generateDiskPath(uploadedfile)
    // returns  C:\Users\RAMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pronghorn\uploads\1
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative Path to Grails test Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603252/relative-path-to-grails-test-directory)

Comment: I'm unit testing a method that generates a path, not store files that contains tests

Comment: Without knowing the generateDiskPath method content it's difficult to say what you're trying to test...